# Customize Windows 8.1 StartScreen by decoding "*.itemdata-ms" binary data file (Windows 8.1, StartScreen, C#)

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, binaryfiles, windows-8.1

I will try to edit the Windows 8.1 StartScreen in a more comfortable and **not** user dependent way.

I know this is not the Microsoft way of using their OS, but in an enterprise environment there must be a way to customize the StartScreen. F.e. if I deploy a new software package there should be the icon on the StartScreen (in the right group, on the pre-defined position).

So, I found the files `appsFolder.itemdata-ms` and `appsFolder.itemdata-ms.bak` both are binary encoded. If I open them in a hex editor there are several group names and links visible but not in a dump format. There is also no way to edit this tiles in the hexeditor in the way it is needed.

**Part of appsFolder.itemdata-ms**

```
?%?????☺↔         ▼   ♠   S t o r e           Y+↨♣♦?BGJ   F   1SPS?w?
```

I tried to write a decoder (used C#), with no success, everything can be viewed but only like it was in the hex editor.

Tried the PowerShell command `Export-StartLayout -as xml` everything was exported in the right way, groups, tiles, positions to:

**export.xml**

```
<launcher version="2">
   <view name="Start">
     <group name="Desktop">
       <tile FencePost="0" size="wide310x150" AppID="Microsoft.Windows.Desktop"/>
       <tile FencePost="0" size="square150x150" AppID="Microsoft.InternetExplorer.Default"/>
       <tile FencePost="0" size="square150x150" AppID="Chrome"/>
     </group>
     <group name="Entwicklung">
       <tile FencePost="0" size="square150x150" AppID="{7C5A40EF-A0FB-4BFC-874A-C0F2E0B9FA8E}\Fiddler2\Fiddler.exe"/>
       <tile FencePost="0" size="square150x150" AppID="{7C5A40EF-A0FB-4BFC-874A-C0F2E0B9FA8E}\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"/>
      </group>
    </view>
</launcher>
```

But the `Import-StartLayout` does not work as expected, with this command the previously exported layout can **not** be applied to the current user (only by using gpo, but then the startscreen is locked).

I also took [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) to inspect the PowerShell Cmt-Lets but this ended in unmanaged code parts.

To cut a long story short, **is there a way to decode the binary files to edit them (maybe a third party tool?) and write them back to apply the changes to the current user?**

Comment: in Windows 8.1 it's possible to [customize the Start Screen](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj134269.aspx) as part of the operating system deployment.  I'm sure some enterprising 3rd party has already come up with a more granular solution.

Comment: @Luke - I know the method while deployment. but what if a user gets a new software package how can I add this tile to his startscreen on a pre-defined position. But for my own knowledge I hope someone can help me to understand the Microsoft way of handling the startscreen in a more detailed way

Comment: It seems it is also possible to do this via [group policy](http://trekker.net/archives/control-the-windows-8-1-start-screen-layout-with-group-policy/).

Comment: with this way the user can not edit tiles. like I said, for me it suits best if the user has f.e. one group fixed and the rest customizable. And the last and impossible thing is: if a user gets a new software package how can this tile be added to his startscreen? (at the right position)

Comment: Are there any new researches or results maybe with the "new" Windows 8.1 Update 1. I found some heavy changes and very good improvements they made with this Update concerning Apps but nothing to the point of Startscreen customization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible, and that is by-design (not that I agree with that design choice).  I had several arguments with the Windows Product Group about this.

It is similar to the way Microsoft has locked down the Task Bar.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd391692%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> "**Note:** Applications cannot programmatically pin themselves to the
>   taskbar. That functionality is reserved strictly for the user."

Either:

1. You set the Start Screen Tiles for *all* users via group policy or within the image. (locked down environment)
2. You allow the users to customize their desktop as they wish (user defined environment).

Comment: +1, Unfortunately, this is accurate for Window 8. It would be nice as an administrator to be able to provide sensible defaults for my org, but still let users customize beyond that to their preference. I've heard this is coming in 8.1.

Comment: +1 But not that answer I wanted to see. I hope this will change in Windows 8.2 or maybe 9 ;)

Comment: +1, I get the feeling Windows 10 will risk being even worse.  Software from big companies often seems to change like this.  Removing the Quick Launch in Windows as a default is another example which is explained by the Taskbar being a replacement (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/desktop).  what if you want a lot of shortcuts, that would soon fill the width of the taskbar.  If only they could provide more options even if they are hidden by default to make it easier for beginners.

Answer (score 2):

I too am looking at ways to edit the Start Screen data file. I have got it to work via a GPO and I used .Net Reflector to analyse the Export-StartLayout cmdlet. It works by calling a method on a COM interface defined in the windows\system32\twinapi.dll so it is not easy to decode the data file format.

The xml file contains APP IDs which are defined in the registry and can be listed by the PS get-startapps cmdlet so it is possible to create an editor for this.

I work with schools and colleges so there is a heavy requirement to control the desktop. At the moment most of the schools I deal with are keeping away from Windows 8 because of problems like these. Seems the MS just don't listen to what people really need!

Comment: +1 ;) ... I have also successfully edited the xml file and rolled out by gpo. But in our environment there is a need of adding tiles if our software packager installed a software on the client. Additionally there should be the possibilty to force f.e. the first tile group to be fix and the other user handled. But as I see, the more and I have to realize I must tell them to forget this idea

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you export the configuration file in binary format as Import-StartLayout won’t import XML files. Here’s the export command:

```
Export-StartLayout -As BIN -Path CustomStartScreenLayout.bin -Verbose
```